Tabular alignment with dimensions from key-value interface
Is it usual to get
! LaTeX Error: Illegal character in array arg.

when using \l_ditura_width_dim for w{l}{\l_ditura_width_dim}.
Nave noticed that when I just use p{\l_ditura_width_dim} there is no problem.  But the text gets aligned to the right side of the page.
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\dim_new:N \l_ditura_width_dim
\tl_new:N  \l_ditura_name_tl    
\tl_new:N  \l_ditura_role_tl

\keys_define:nn { kvi_ditura }
  {
    width .dim_set:N = \l_ditura_width_dim,
    width .initial:n = 8cm,
    %% width .default:n = ,
    width .value_required:n = false,
    width .usage = general,

    name .tl_set:N = \l_ditura_name_tl,
    name .initial:n = ,
    %name .default:n = ,
    name .value_required:n = false,
    name .usage = general,

    role .tl_set:N = \l_ditura_role_tl,
    role .initial:n = ,
    % role .default:n = ,
    role .value_required:n = false,
    role .usage = general,
}

\NewDocumentCommand {\ditura} { m }
  {
    \keys_set:nn {kvi_ditura} {#1}

    \begin {flushright}
      \begin {tabular} { @{} w{l}{\l_ditura_width_dim} @{} }
        \tl_if_blank:VF \l_ditura_name_tl
          { \tl_use:N \l_ditura_name_tl \\ }     
        \tl_if_blank:VF \l_ditura_role_tl
          { \tl_use:N \l_ditura_role_tl \\ }
      \end {tabular}
    \end {flushright}
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin {document}

\ditura {name={Likku Cirillu}, role=Sailor}
\ditura {name={Frillu Grillu}, role=Fisherman}

\end {document}


yes it is usual to get such an error if the array package is not loaded.

any documentation that told you that the w column spec existed would have told you to load array package to define it. You should have made a minimal example without all the unrelated keyval setting.

"But the text gets aligned to the right side of the page." what else do you expect since you have used flushright ?

Yes.  But then within the tabular I want alignment to the left for consecutive calls to the command.  Requiring the package array has resolved the problem.

does p{width} provide alignment ? What is the advantage of using w{l}{5cm} over p{width}.

l columns are mbox so single line, p are parbox so linebreak to the specified width. the text would not be right aligned in a p column as the alignment is reset.

I want left alignment within tabular with specified width.

Then, the correct approach would be w{l}{5cm}. Because I want Likku Cirillu and Frillu Grillu to left align on the right side of the page.
